# Basic server build for practicing and learning linux on

Tags: 12.04, server, users, dns, openssh

I am taking it upon myself to learn Linux,so here is what I want to accomplish; I want to set up a server primarily for practice. I don't need it to do anything specific accept allow me to login via ssh. I have attempted this before and had the following issues: 
 - My dns kept changing and the only way to log into the server was to use the site "whatsmyip" to log directly into my home network. I was able to login when I am sitting at home, but if I was to go to "StarBucks or any place like that I wasn't able to login.

Comment: And your question is..?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a free service like http://www.noip.com/ - you'll get free no-ip subdomains and you can run a little service on your Linux box that communicates with their servers and adjusts DNS records if they need to be changed.

I use it at home, it's great!

Edit: Another way you could do this could be to create a Virtual Machine on your Windows or Mac laptop using virtualbox - you can download it from https://www.virtualbox.org/.

Then, from inside the Virtual Machine, you could turn on SSH if you wanted to. You could then SSH to it from your laptop as if it were a server on the internet.

Comment: and Kurt0015- Thanks for the good suggestions. I have tried DynDns, but that is no longer free and as for noip.com, I really don't understand how to set up the Linux updater software on my Linux laptop. Also running running a virtual machine slows my laptop sometimes. I'm not putting your suggestions down, so please don't think that. I am willing to try "noip" again if I can figure out how to install the software.

Answer (score 0):

First off all you need to select a linux version i recommend ubuntu or debian but its a personal choice. If you choose ubuntu server in the setup you could setup ssh. Because your ip is constantly changing you will need a program that updates your ip adress. So you could just remember a url and you will know that the ip adress is correct.

A possible ip updater DynDNS: http://dyn.com/support/clients/linux/
It keeps your ip up to date with a sub-domainname or a real domainname.

Answer (score 0):

honestly, i went the same route you did at first. With the relative cheapness of second level domains it might be ALOT easy if you register a low cost domain and forward the nameserver for that name to a ddns service (I love dnsexit.com) they are both easy to setup and will save you TONS of issues. That way, if you want it to be more later then one step is already done and configured. 1and1.com has the easiest domain interface (i feel) but godaddy seems to have more flexibility. (I use both).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using Vagrant.... works on all os's, it's what I use.... requires virtual box and you can find concise documentation at http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/ I think.